# get one specific line of comment as header with python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, header, comments

I have a file looking like

```
# Comment 1
# Comment 2
# A B C
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

How to read it with python pandas module, so as the last line of comments can be interpreted as the columns titles ?

I've tried

```
pandas.read_table(file_path, header= 2 , comment='#' )
```

But the comment lines are eliminated first, thus the header line will be 
`7 8 9`

Answer (score 4):

```
In [7]: pd.read_csv('test.csv',skiprows=2,sep='\s+',escapechar='#')
Out[7]: 
    A  B  C
0   1  2  3
1   4  5  6
2   7  8  9
```

`escapechar` tell that `#` must be consider as a end of field.   Here it is used as a clean workaround. `sep='\s+'` is required here because you have trailing space after 3 and 6 in your file (or this page.)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this manually: first read the comments, parse the column names, then call `read_table`:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

def read_data(path):
    with open(path) as handle:
        *_comments, names = itertools.takewhile(
            lambda line: line.startswith('#'), handle)

        # This is not the most robust way, adjust for your needs :)
        names = names[1:].split()

    return pandas.read_table(path, header=0, names=names, sep=' ', comment='#')
```