# Python Pandas: get column names from inbetween comments

Tags: pandas

Similar to this post [get one specific line of comment as header with python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772656/get-one-specific-line-of-comment-as-header-with-python-pandas)

How can I get the column names in between comments using only pandas?

File.csv:

```
#Comment1
#Col1|Col2|Col3
#Comment2 
data1|data2|data3
```

I am able to do it with some preprocess but can this be done using pandas only?

using `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='|')` + any other parameters

My expected output would be:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1: data1 data2 data3
```

Somehow I have tried leaving `#comments2` in the dataframe using `headers=1` but it changed the data types of my columns to string. Then doing some manipulation on the data frame(checking of row has a string and dropping it) and converting it back to float adds value to my original data(IE 1.0005 -> 1.0005XXXXXX). Determining that what I experiment on was such a hassle compared to having a preprocess to collect the column names from the comments and adding `names=col_name` and `comments='#'` to the data frame instance.

Comment: please show your expected output

Comment: Please show your input as well...is that a dataframe you're showing?

Comment: Updated my post. I can achieve what my expected output would be but I have to do some pre-processes to get the header from the comments. If i use `header=2`, the `#comment2`  will still be encoded in the data frame. Adding `comments='#'` will remove the comments without reading the header line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read the file twice: once for header and once for data.

```
headers = pd.read_csv(path, sep='|', skiprows=1, nrows=0).columns.str.strip('#')
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='|', skiprows=3, header=None, names=headers)
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm having `UserWarning: Duplicate names specified. This will raise an error in the future. return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)`

Printing the data frame:
`Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Col1, Col2, Col3]
Index: []
`

It does the job but I can't seem to find what are these duplicates and the warning that might cause me error in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
lines = []
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line[0] == '#':
            continue
        lines.append(line))
split_lines = ['|'.split(line) for line in lines]
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Col1' : split_lines[0], 'Col2' : split_lines[1], 'Col3' : split_lines[2]}])
```

Comment: This is what my pre-process looks like. reading the file first to get the column name from the comments then when building the data frame just plug in the list.